# Compare Color Toargb

Tags: c#, colors

I want compare two .toargb colors in a while with threading:

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
do
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++)
        {
            //Get the color at each pixel
            Color now_color = bmp.GetPixel(j, i);

                                       
            if (now_color.ToArgb() == pictureBox22.BackColor.ToArgb())
            {
                IsColorFound = true;
                      
                Thread.Sleep(300);

                bmp.Dispose();
                break;
            }
            
        }
        if (IsColorFound == true)
        {
            bmp.Dispose();
            break;
        }
        
    }

} while (IsColorFound != true);
}
```

Thats never compare BUT when i click ON runtime, a button, to change the color pictureBox22.BackColor it works immediately.
what was the problem. I change with the button to the same color as i defined in Designer.

Comment: _in a while with threading_ ???

Comment: sry yes this is in backgroundworker dowork event.